# Confusion about the term Azure ExpressRoute Partner

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

**Question**: What is an `Azure ExpressRoute Partner`?

From what I know `ExpressRoute` is an Azure service that lets you create private connections between Microsoft datacenters and infrastructure that’s on your premises or in a colocation facility. But the term `Partner` in the following official Azure article got me confused. The related links provided in the article did not help me either.

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview) official documentation about Azure Virtual Network, the section `Communicate with on-premises resource` describes one option of communicating between on-premise resource(s) and Azure Network as follows:

**Azure ExpressRoute**: `Established between your network and Azure, through an ExpressRoute partner. This connection is private. Traffic does not go over the internet.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExpressRoute connections do not go over the public Internet. It's over a private connection facilitated by a connectivity provider. So Partner is the [service provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-locations#locations) or connectivity provider, you need to order an ExpressRoute circuit through the service provider to connect to Azure. Look at the [ExpressRoute circuits and peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-circuit-peerings) and how to [create and modify an ExpressRoute circuit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-howto-circuit-portal-resource-manager).

[image]
Read more [ExpressRoute FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-faqs)